# Usage of microsoftTeams.shareDeepLink

Tags: microsoft-teams

I try to generate a deep link to a subEntityId in a Microsoft Teams group tab. When I call

```
microsoftTeams.shareDeepLink({
  subEntityId: "myid",
  subEntityLabel: "123"
}
);
```

I get this dialog (my tab is called 'Interactive':

[image]

As you can see, there is no URL in the text field but the label, which was appended with the tab's name. I don't see out https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links on how to use `shareDeepLink` and I don't see how else I could use it to generate a URL. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the deep link generation works fine, but the texbox contains a rich text link instead of the actual URL. So copying it into a rich text block will work, but not inside into the browser's URL field.

Answer (score -1):

You need to generate the Deeplink

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<appId>/<entityId>?webUrl=<entityWebUrl>&label=<entityLabel>&context=<context>
```

You need to replace the appid,entityid,weburl,label and in context you need to add your encoded subentity id.

microsoftTeams.shareDeepLink('url');

Comment: This does not work for me. Neither the generated URL works (none of the app ids I have works; if I use the one you get when you copy the link to the whole tab, I get the view of the app in the store). I also can't call shareDeepLink with a string.